# Why is Java showing Tomcat 9 and 7 is greyed out when I have Tomcat 7?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

Can someone help me?[image]

I am using Xammp as server located in C drive

Answer (score 1):

You project is using a JavaEE version that's only available with tomcat 9.  In your project facets, try downgrading the version of Dynamic Web Module

Comment: ok thanks however I cannot seem to change the Project Facet...

It says cannot change dynamic web module to 2.4

[1]: http://i.imgur.com/tZYHRNS.jpg

Comment: ok thanks again....I think I need to change my Web.XML parameters in order to be able to change the Dynamic Web Module...wow that is complicated stuff!